# Under what circumstances is the solution to $y(x+1) = y(x)$ unique?

Tags: functional-analysis

There's infinitely many solutions to just $y(x+1)=y(x),$ but, what do I need for the solution to be unique? In other functional equations, you might do it with an initial condition like $y(0)=a,$ but I'm concerned this isn't enough either.

Comment: Do you have an example of where $y(x+1)=y(x),y(0)=a$ has infinite distinct solutions?

Comment: Trig functions that have an increasing frequency for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but which start at the same value, like $\sin(2 \pi n x).$ The condition alone doesn't rule out that $y(x)$ can also equal $y(1/2)$ and $y(1/3)$ and so on.